# Powershell regex search and append multiple values

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

Below I have a ps1 for finding and appending text defined by regex pattern; i.e. from [pattern] to [pattern]Foo. Is there a simpler way to do this for multiple regex patterns, other than defining each regex as pattern2, pattern3, etc. and creating a separate "ForEach" to correspond to every regex? Because that's how I did it, and it works but it looks very rudimentary.

```
$pattern1 = [regex]'([___)'
$pattern2 = [regex]'([___)'

Get-ChildItem 'C:\\File\\Location\\*.txt' -Recurse | ForEach {
     (Get-Content $_ | 
     ForEach  { $_ -replace $pattern1, ('$1'+'FOO')} | 
     ForEach  { $_ -replace $pattern2, ('$1'+'FOO')}) |
     Set-Content $_
}
```

Comment: You may use alternations: `[regex]'(pattern1|pattern2)'`

Comment: BTW `[` needs an escape `\[` otherwise it's an invalid pattern. Also, use `-raw` parameter in Get-Content if you're on PowerShell 3 or newer to make processing much faster.

Comment: You can chain `-replace` such as `Get-Content $_ -replace $pattern1, '$1FOO' -replace $pattern2, '$1FOO'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are replacing with the same replacement pattern, just use [*alternation*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
$pattern = [regex]'(pattern1|pattern2)'
```

**NOTE**: in unanchored alternations, you should watch out for the order of the alternatives: if a shorter branch can match at the same location in string, a longer one - if it is present after the shorter one - won't get tested. E.g. `(on|one|ones)` will only match `on` in `ones`. See more about that in the [*Remember That The Regex Engine Is Eager*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).